# Boost.Asio - not executing all handlers

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to create an adaptor for `boost::io_context`, that will always pick a handler with the highest priority among ready ones to execute. I took the inspiration from [the official example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp), but quickly ran into unexpected behavior in a scenario, where one handler starts another asynchronous operation in the same context.

Here is the [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/957e788968b100e0). I have only modified the user code (below `//---`), to call a low priority handler, after which I would expect the high and middle priority handlers to be invoked. Only the low priority handler is called.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class handler_priority_queue
{
public:
  void add(int priority, boost::function<void()> function)
  {
    handlers_.push(queued_handler(priority, function));
  }

  void execute_all()
  {
    while (!handlers_.empty())
    {
      queued_handler handler = handlers_.top();
      handler.execute();
      handlers_.pop();
    }
  }

  // A generic wrapper class for handlers to allow the invocation to be hooked.
  template <typename Handler>
  class wrapped_handler
  {
  public:
    wrapped_handler(handler_priority_queue& q, int p, Handler h)
      : queue_(q), priority_(p), handler_(h)
    {
    }

    void operator()()
    {
      handler_();
    }

    template <typename Arg1>
    void operator()(Arg1 arg1)
    {
      handler_(arg1);
    }

    template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
    void operator()(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)
    {
      handler_(arg1, arg2);
    }

  //private:
    handler_priority_queue& queue_;
    int priority_;
    Handler handler_;
  };

  template <typename Handler>
  wrapped_handler<Handler> wrap(int priority, Handler handler)
  {
    return wrapped_handler<Handler>(*this, priority, handler);
  }

private:
  class queued_handler
  {
  public:
    queued_handler(int p, boost::function<void()> f)
      : priority_(p), function_(f)
    {
    }

    void execute()
    {
      function_();
    }

    friend bool operator<(const queued_handler& a,
        const queued_handler& b)
    {
      return a.priority_ < b.priority_;
    }

  private:
    int priority_;
    boost::function<void()> function_;
  };

  std::priority_queue<queued_handler> handlers_;
};

// Custom invocation hook for wrapped handlers.
template <typename Function, typename Handler>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function f,
    handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h)
{
  h->queue_.add(h->priority_, f);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void high_priority_handler()
{
  std::cout << "High priority handler\n";
}

void middle_priority_handler()
{
  std::cout << "Middle priority handler\n";
}

void low_priority_handler(
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
  handler_priority_queue& pri_queue)
{
  std::cout << "Low priority handler\n";

  io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(1, middle_priority_handler));
  io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(2, high_priority_handler));
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  handler_priority_queue pri_queue;

  // Post a completion handler to be run immediately.
  io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(
      0, std::bind(low_priority_handler,
                   std::ref(io_service), std::ref(pri_queue))));

  while (io_service.run_one())
  {
    // The custom invocation hook adds the handlers to the priority queue
    // rather than executing them from within the poll_one() call.
    while (io_service.poll_one())
      ;

    pri_queue.execute_all();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I call `io_service.restart()` after the loop in `main` and copy-paste the same loop after that, the remaining handlers are executed, and in the expected order. When debugging, I could see that a handler was enqueued in `asio_handler_invoke` only once.

Why did `boost::io_context` stop running after the first handler? Is what I am asking for possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io_context` stops because there are not any ready handlers to run while `poll_one` is called.

[1] First handler is posted:

```
io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(0, std::bind(low_priority_handler,
                   std::ref(io_service), std::ref(pri_queue))));
```

[2]  `while (io_service.run_one())`

waits until there is one ready handler to run

[3] in `run_one()` handler is executed. You have defined `asio_handler_invoke()` which provides some strategy to call a function (body) of handler. Default strategy just calls function, in your case function object is queued into `handler_priority_queue`, but `io_service's` queue doesn't receive handlers to be executed. So, when body of `low_priority_handler` (which adds new handlers for `io_service` by calling `io_service.post`) is executed? This function is executed from `pri_queue.execute_all()` (**which is called after `poll_one`**), not during the call of `poll_one()`. `io_service.poll_one()` marks `io_service` as stopped when there is not any ready handler to run. This is your case. You can reset `io_service` after `pri_queue.execute_all()`, then all handlers will be called.